# How to hide / show widget onclick on other widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this: two widgets on the same page:

```
  _buildMyWidget() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: true,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0),

              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So, what I want is to change the `visible: true` to `visible: false` when I click on the `Text.rich` "Click me" button here below. How can I achieve this?

```
_buildMyWidget2() {
    return Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
              vertical: 15,
            ),
            child: Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "Pf"),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "Click me",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        );
}
```

Comment: could you please add full code to see how these two widget related to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

first define:

```
 bool isVisibel = false;
```

then:

```
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: isVisibel,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0),
                    width: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 20,
              vertical: 15,
            ),
            child: Text.rich(
              TextSpan(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                children: [
                  TextSpan(text: "Pf"),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "Click me",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          setState(() {
                            isVisibel = !isVisibel;
                          });
                        }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

result when `isVisibel` is false:

[image]

result when `isVisibel` is true:

[image]

Comment: This code is not giving me any errors, but clicking on it does not do anything...

Comment: I test it, it Work!, what expect to see?

Comment: Well, that if I click, it will show/hide the other container. I can't get it to work, hmm.

Comment: see the image I attach. when isVisibel is true, it add some space to above it.

Comment: Very weird. I can't get the same effect. It basically needs to toggle the widget but it does not.

Comment: where did you define isVisibel? is it out of build method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247890/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-johan).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming those two widgets are inside the same widget/page; you could define a boolean data and assign it to visibility. On tap, just toggle the boolean data

```html
bool show = true;




TextSpan(
        text: ' Click here',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[300]),
        recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()..onTap = () {
          setState({ show = !show; });
        },
      ),
      
      
Visibility(
      visible: show,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0),

              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Getting a: error: The setter 'onTap' isn't defined for the type 'GestureRecognizer'.  error

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable and change its value.

```
 bool visi = true;
    

return Visibility(
      visible: visi,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 5.0),

              width: 120,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And change its value when user click on RichText.

```
return GestureDetector(
onTap:(){
visi = !visi;
setState(){}
}
child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
          vertical: 15,
        ),
        child: Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            children: [
              TextSpan(text: "Pf"),
              TextSpan(
                text: "Click me",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Where do I put that boolean?

Comment: Also, this does not do anything for me, sadly. When I click, nothing happens at all.